# Passing a `MPI_Request*` to the send/recv functions

Tags: mpi

Below are two ways of writing what is seemingly (to me at least) exactly the same thing:

```cpp
void do_some_work(MPI_Request* send_reqs, int* send_counter) {
    for (int i = 0; i < someNumber; ++i) {
        // working version
        MPI_Request req = send_reqs[*send_counter];
        MPI_Isend(ptr, n_elem, M_MPI_REAL, trg_rank, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
                    
        // buggy version...
        MPI_Request* req = &send_reqs[*send_counter];
        MPI_Isend(ptr, n_elem, M_MPI_REAL, trg_rank, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req);

        // increment the counter
        (*send_counter)++;
    }
}

// [...]

// Allocate the request array & start the sends
MPI_Request* send_reqs = (MPI_Request*)calloc(someNumber, sizeof(MPI_Request));
int send_counter = 0;
do_some_work(send_reqs, &send_counter);

// [...]

// later on, at the sync step:
MPI_Waitall(send_counter, send_reqs, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
```

However, in practice, the second one triggers random memory access errors (it has exactly the same symptoms as if MPI were writing random stuff all over the place, sometimes triggering segmentation faults or simply modifying values it shouldn't). To add to the weirdness of the issue, the code below works for 3 MPI ranks or less and starts acting out for 4 or 5 ranks (didn't test with more ranks).

Does anyone have any idea or explanation as to what changes and why one works while the other does not ?

Comment: Please add the code that passes your reuests to any `MPI_Wait` function.

Comment: Done, it's a simple `MPI_Waitall` on all the posted send/recv though

Comment: The first code cannot work. `req` is its own object, which is initialized by copy in the first line. You put the request into `req`, but you later wait on the element in `send_reqs`, which is not the same object.  The second way you show avoids this problem.

Comment: I'm also confused by how `send_counter` is used as an integer in the last line, but apparently as a pointer in indexing into `send_reqs`. I think you need to show a complete piece of code.

Comment: yeah apologies for the pointer confusion, I updated the code so it's (hopefully) more clear for everyone (the actual code is fairly big, the only lines of interests are the two highlighted)

Comment: Surprisingly, the first code is the one working... and the second one is not x)

Comment: OK, I'm actually just a gigantic moron: @WolfgangBangerth is right, the first way is wrong (as it should be, this is reassuring x). I didn't allocate a request array big enough, hence the errors I got with the second way (and the first way 'hid' the issue by passing a copy...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, the issue was that the request array wasn't big enough. Thus, the first two lines were hiding the memory allocation issue by creating copies of a non-existing `MPI_Request` (how it didn't bug out in the `MPI_Waitall` I've got no idea though)